# Optimizing bounds?

Tags: calculus

Pretty much trying to optimize the bounds of a function (or window when using a graphing calculator).

So the function is $=e^{-x}\sin(x)$, with $x\geq0$.

When taking the derivative I get $-\sin(x)+\cos(x)$.  Setting it equal to $0$, I get $x=\pi/4$ and $x=5\pi/4$.

Graphing it on my calculator, it appears that the $y$ doesn't go more than about $.3$ when $x > 0$.

This isn't close to either of my critical points.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x = \pi/4$, then $e^{-x} \sin(x) \approx 0.322396942$, which agrees with your graphing calculator.

Comment: Gotcha, forgot to plug it back in! thanks!